# Returning array length stored in array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm attempting to simply return stored array values using different method calls and substring values etc. in my code. My issue is that in my terminal output-my array length is one value too large in length.

7 words, stored in an ArrayList

```
apple
bannana
peach
plum
orange
lime
```

5 words, stored in an ArrayList

```
apple
peach
plum
lime
```

**When it should look like this:**

6 words, stored in an ArrayList

```
apple
bannana
peach
plum
orange
lime
```

4 words, stored in an ArrayList

```
apple
peach
plum
lime
```

So I'm trying to figure out where I could be missing something.
My code looks like this:

```
/**
 * Create an ArrayList<String> instance, and
 * assign it to wordList.
 */
public Words( )
{
    this.wordList = new ArrayList<String>();
    populate( );
}

//     public ArrayList<String> getWordList( )
//     {
//         return this.wordList;
//     }

/**
 * returns the size of wordList
 * 
 * @return int
 */
public int count( )
{
    return wordList.size()-1;
}

/**
 * Done
 */
public void populate( )
{
    String[ ] spellings = 
        { 
            new String( "" ),
            new String( "1234" ),

            "a99le",

            "apple",               
            "bannana",
            "peach",

            new String( "plum" ),

            "orange",
            "lime"
        };

    for (String s: spellings)
    {
        this.addWord( s );

    }
}

/*
 * Creates and returns a String[ ] array of all String elements
 * that are included in the wordList field.
 * 
 * @return a String[ ] array
 */
public String[ ] copyToWordArray( )
{
    String[]wordArray = new String[wordList.size()];

    for (int n = 0; n < wordArray.length; n++ )
    {
        wordArray[n] = wordList.get(n);
    }
    return wordArray;
}

/*
 * Creates and returns an ArrayList of all String elements 
 * in wordList that contain the given substring.
 * 
 * @return ArrayList<String>
 * @param String substring
 */
public ArrayList<String> contains( String substring )
{
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String s: wordList)
    {
        if (s.contains(substring))
        {
            list.add(s);
        }
    }

    return list;
}

/*
 * Creates and returns an ArrayList of all String elements
 * in wordList that start with the given prefix.
 * 
 * @return ArrayList<String>
 * @param  String prefix
 */
public ArrayList<String> startsWith( String prefix )
{
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (String s: wordList)
    {
        if (s.startsWith(prefix))
        {
            list.add(s);
        }
    }

    return list;
}

/**
 * Searches wordList with a for-each loop, and 
 * returns the word if it is found. Otherwise,
 * returns null.
 * 
 * @return String
 * @param String word
 */
public String find( String word )
{
    for (String s: wordList)
    { 
        if (s.equals(word))
        {
            return s;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 *  For a word to be valid:
 *    1) word.length() is postive,
 *    2) word contains alphabetic characters exclusively.
 *    
 *  This method uses a for loop to examine each character 
 *  in the given word.
 *  
 *  it returns:
 *    - false for the first non-alphabetic character detected. 
 *    - true if all characters in the given word are strictly
 *      alphabetic, and the word length is positive.
 *  
 *  @return true or false
 *  @param  String str
 */
private boolean isValidWord( String str )
{
    if (str.length() > 0 && str!= null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
        {
            if (!Character.isLetter(str.charAt(i)))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

/**
 * Calls addWord( s ) for each element s in the String[ ] array
 * to add them to wordList.
 * 
 * @param String[ ] spellings
 */
public void addWords( String[ ] spellings )
{
    for (String s: spellings)
    {
        wordList.add(s);
    }
}

/**
 *  This method calls the find method to determine
 *  whether the given word is already in wordList.
 *  There are two cases: find returns either 
 *  1) null -- word not found in wordList -- or 
 *  2) the word -- the one that it found.
 *  

 *     
 *
 *  
 *  @param  String word
 */
public void add( String word )
{
    String w = this.find( word );

    if (w == null)
    {
        wordList.add(word);

    }
    return;
}

/**
 *  If the given word is valid, this method calls the add( word ) method. 
 * 
 *  
 *  @param  String str
 */
public void addWord( String str )
{
    if (isValidWord( str ))
    {
        this.add(str); 
    }

}

/**
 *  This method calls the find method. Two cases: 
 *  find returns either null or the word that was found.
 *  
 *  If the given word is found, the method removes
 *  it from the wordList, 
 *     
 *  
 *  
 *  @param  String word
 */
public void remove( String word )
{
    String w = this.find( word );

    if (w == null )
    {
        message = "The word cannot be removed from list.";
    }
    else
    {
        wordList.remove(word);
    }
}

/**
 *  This method, on the condition that there is an nth element
 *  in wordList, removes the given word from the location.
 * 
 *  
 *  @param  n
 */
public void remove( int n )
{
    if (n < this.wordList.size( ))
    {

        wordList.remove(n);
    }
}

/**
 * Done
 */
public String toString( )
{
    String str = wordList.size( ) + " words, stored in an ArrayList<String>";
    for (String c: wordList)
    {
        str += "\n\t" + c.toString( );
    }
    return str + "\n";
}


/**
 * Done
 */
public static void main( String[ ] args )
{
    System.out.println( "" );
    Words words = new Words( );

    System.out.println( words.toString( ) );
    System.out.println( );

    words.add( "lemon" );

    words.add( "lemon" );

    words.remove( "lemon" );

    words.remove( "lemon" );
    words.remove( words.count( ) - 1 );

    words.remove( "bannana" );

    System.out.println( words.toString( ) );
    String[ ] wordArray = words.copyToWordArray( );
    System.out.println( wordArray.length + " words, stored in a String[ ] array" );
    for (String w: wordArray)
    {
        System.out.println( "\t" + w.toString( ) );
    }
    System.out.println( );

    ArrayList<String> list = words.contains( "p" );
    System.out.println( list.size( ) + " words that contain letter p" );
    for (String w: list)
    {
        System.out.println( "\t" + w.toString( ) );
    }
    System.out.println( );

    list = words.startsWith( "p" );
    System.out.println( list.size( ) + " words that start with letter p" );
    for (String w: list)
    {
        System.out.println( "\t" + w.toString( ) );
    }
    System.out.println( );
}
```

}

It is probably something very simple that I am missing but I am not catching it--Thank you in advance.

Comment: `array.length` is rock solid.  I'm looking at your code mountain right now, trying to verify my assumption that you are ending up with an empty string at either the beginning or the end of your array.

Comment: You misspelt banana.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem might be in the `addWords` method. In all of your other `add` methods you have checked that the string passed in is valid, but this one just adds the strings directly from the array passed in. This is the method that is used when you populate the ArrayList in the `populate` method called from the constructor.

The `populate` method adds an empty string to the `spellings` array which is added to the ArrayList. If you check the validity of the strings in the array passed into `addWords` then this empty string won't be added to the ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

And that was quicker than I thought it might be.  As I supposed in my comment, you have an empty string in your array.  Observe in your `populate()` method that the first `String` you add to your internal list is

```
    new String( "" ),
```

that is, an empty string.  As far as I can tell, you never afterward remove it.  When you print out the contents, you count and print that element, but you apparently miss it because the corresponding output takes the form of a blank line.

If you put the empty string somewhere in the middle of the list instead then you'll see it more easily.  Alternatively, you could output quotes around your words, or do some other thing that allows you to distinguish output words from ordinary blank space.

Comment: Perfect. I merely removed the empty string in the populate() method and I got the desired output.  Should I place empty strings elsewhere in the future or not insert them whatsoever in similar methods? Thank you.

Comment: You should use empty strings wherever and however is appropriate.  Your issue seems to have been not so much your use of an empty string, but rather a misinterpretation of the output.  If an empty or space-only string is supposed to be an allowed element, then you should consider outputting quotes around each word.  Otherwise, you should avoid adding them or allowing them to be added.

Answer (score 0):

You're defining your count to be `worList.size()-1`, when it should be just `wordlist.size()`;

```
public int count( )
{
    return wordList.size()-1;
}
```

Comment: count() is only used as the index from the wordList, so size() - 1 gives the index of the last position. However when it is used in the main method it calls remove(count()-1) so this is actually removing the second last wordList element.

Comment: Okay, so probably a bug, but definitely not the root cause.

Comment: Agreed, definitely something to look into. If nothing else it is a bit misleading